# schedule testNG testcase using Jenkins to connect to hadoop(hive)

Tags: java, hadoop, jenkins, hive, scheduler

I am trying to schedule a testNG testcase using local Jenkings for establishing connection to hive.
But for some reason this is failing with no error in the output console but I am able to establish connection to oracle teradata and hana. Similarly when I am running the testNG testcase through eclipse,it is working.The only issue is while trying to connect it through Jenkins.

```
[Output of the following code snippet][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZKvQ.jpg

public class hiveconntester {
    private static String hivedriverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
  @Test
  public void f() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

      ResultSet hiveres=null;

          System.out.println("Fetching Hive Data");
          Class.forName(hivedriverName);

          /*********** Hive ***************/

          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("server", "username", "password");
          System.out.println("******* Returning hive  ***********"); 
        Statement hivestmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

    System.out.println("******* Returning hive resultset ***********"); 
  }
}
```